# How to convert EC public key in PEM format to DER format using openssl

Tags: openssl, cryptography

With a public key as **PEM**, how can this be converted to **DER** format using **openssl**?  Please note that this is not a x509 certificate.  Also this question is about EC (ECDSA) public keys not RSA and using **openssl** not C, C++ or some other programming language

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxx
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
openssl pkey -pubin -in ec_pub.pem -outform DER -out ec_pub.der
```

Comment: openssl ec -inform PEM -outform DER -pubin -in mypublic.pem.key -out mypublic.der.key

Comment: You can answer your own questions on here...

Comment: @code2535 This answer look OK , see `man openssl-pkey`. Did you have any issue?

Comment: https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html lists a PEM -> DER conversion command for x509, but my reading of `man openssl-ec` indicates similar options will work for elliptic curve keys (`openssl ec` instead of `openssl x509`).

Comment: When I looked on the internet, I did not find the answer.  After posting this question, I found it with openssl ec as I posted as a comment to @garethTheRed answer.  I did not answer my own question as I do not have enough reputation points yet.  I prefer the openssl ec to openssl pkey but that is just a perference

Answer (score 1):

The PEM format consists of `-----BEGIN …-----` line, a Base64-encoded body and an `-----END …-----` line. If you just want to convert to DER (binary), you just need to extract the body and convert it from Base64 to binary.

(This is for plaintext, i.e. non-encrypted files. Encrypted PEM files have additional information that describes the encryption method. You typically can't usefully just extract the DER, you have to decrypt it, because the Base64-encoded part doesn't have any metadata about the encryption method.)

You can do this generically with the [`openssl enc -base64`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-enc.html) command, which can be abbreviated to `openssl base64`.

```
openssl base64 -d -in myfile.pem -out myfile.der
```

Note that if you wanted to use a straight Base64 decoder, such as `base64`, you would need to strip of the begin/end lines.

```
<myfile.pem grep '^[^-]' | base64 -d >myfile.der
```

Alternatively, with `openssl`, you can use the management command that's specific to the particular kind of data you're dealing with. (Many kinds of data can be handled by more than one openssl command, for various reasons.) Manipulating a `PUBLIC KEY` is the job of [`openssl pkey`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/openssl-pkey.html). Pass `-outform DER` to indicate that you want DER output (`-inform PEM` is optional because that's the default). Pass `-pubin` to indicate that the input is a public key (by default, `openssl pkey` expects a private key).

```
openssl pkey -pubin -in myfile.pem -outform DER -out myfile.der
```

If you happen to know that the key is an EC key, `openssl ec -pubin -in myfile.pem -outform DER` also works, but there's no advantage in using `ec` unless you need the command to work with antique versions of OpenSSL that are no longer supported.